# How to power PSOC 5LP from boost converter

Tags: psoc

I have the CY8CKIT-050 PSOC 5LP development kit, and I have read that I can power my chip though boost converter ([Page 16, last line](https://www.cypress.com/file/45276/download)), but I don't find any place where get information about how to configure boost converter to power the chip. I tried just to disconnect the usb supply but as I expected, the boost converter didn't power the PSOC.

Incidentally, I don't have any components connected to the PSOC, just the power supply to the boost converter and the USB connected to my laptop.

I hope someone can help me. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: ON page 22 we can read: " Figure 4-7 shows the boost converter. To enable the boost convertor functionality, make the following hardware changes on the board. Populate resistors R25, R27 (populated by default), R29, and R31 with 0-Ohm resistors. Ensure that R1 and R28 are not populated. After making these changes, you can configure the project to create a boost convertor-based design. The input power supply to the boost converter must be provided through the test points marked Vbatand GND. "

Comment: I have already made proyects with boost converter, so it's working, but I don't know hot to power the psoc just with the boost converter

Comment: Did you add a 0-Ohm resistor (jumper) R25 and R26? And remove R1 and R28?